# Guitar is not tuning right

Tags: guitar, tuning, beginner

I have a guitar and I love it, and then I broke a string. I fixed it and I am positive I used the right string, I triple checked! But now about a month and a half later, I was tuning my guitar, and doesn't reach the G. I tried my best, I tried tuning it myself, but it doesn’t sound like other G strings on records and apps. I have tried to start as low as it would go without breaking and working my way up. But I can not get it back to being a G without snapping a string! How can I fix this? I am new, so be ear is really hard and it doesn’t work any ways. I got my guitar at a guitar center, can they help me there? Or give me advice for free if I take it in?

When you answer please use simpler terms, because I am new, I might not get it, I really only have started practice chords and strumming and a little tabs.

Comment: Update: it has steel strings! And it is acoustic! Also I can’t find any apps with good tuners that are reading the right string!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and prove read? Some typos make it hard to read. Do I understand correctly that the G-string was broken? How often you've tuned the guitar since replacing the string? Do you tune by pitchfork/ear or are you using a tuning device (or an other way)?

Comment: Are you using the "5-5-5-5-4" method? The fifth fret on the D is the exact note for open G. Also, is it snapping up at the tuning machine, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Does the new string look the same thickness as the old string ? They vary quite a lot on steel-strung acoustic guitars: The G string can be wound (usually copper colour) or not (just a straight bit of wire) depending on the 'weight' (actuall: thickness) of the string.

If you can't get it tight enough to get to G, it could be that the tuning pegs need some attention, or the part where you attach it over the bridge (other end to tuning pegs) might be at fault.

If there's any flex, for example the tuning peg can move about, or the bridge has movement, or the guitar body itself is flexing (unlikely) then the string will be very difficult to tune.

Whatever the issue, your guitar centre will be able to help, probably for free. It'd be good for you to take it in and ask them to show you how it's fixed, so you learn a bit abbout maintenance too.

Enjoy - and welcome to the hugely cool family :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrapped in the correct direction?  There is a method for wrapping the string around the tuning peg and a correct direction (above/below) with respect to the direction of the peg.  Check out this blog.

https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/how-to-change-electric-guitar-strings/

Even if it doesn't match your guitar exactly the principle is discussed.  You can look for more examples.  If the string is not wrapped around the peg properly it will slip very easily out of tune.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is breaking at the same place in the length of the string as you try to bring it up to tuning,(most often  the bridge) you may have a point where the string is being bent over a relatively sharp edge or pinched in such  a way that it is unduly stressed  at that point. Also the string should be able to move freely in  the string slots in the bridge and the nut when tuning. A little nut grease will usually help make that possible.